# Как задать цвета фона активной TabItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

У меня есть 2 столбца, допустим Name И Female. Когда не один из них не выбран, они по умолчанию темные, но после нажатия на столбец он меняет цвет на белый, как это исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
       <TabItem x:Name="nicknameTab" Background="Black" BorderBrush="Black">
           <TabItem.Header>
               <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Black">
                   <TextBlock Margin="3" Background="Black" Foreground="White">Name</TextBlock>
               </StackPanel>
           </TabItem.Header>
           <TabItem.Content>
               <StackPanel Background="Black">
                   <RadioButton IsChecked="True">Jhon</RadioButton>
                   <RadioButton>Andrew</RadioButton>
                   <RadioButton>Max</RadioButton>
               </StackPanel>
           </TabItem.Content>
       </TabItem>
    
   </TabControl>
```

Comment: Покажите разметку, пока ничего не понятно

Comment: @АндрейNOP Обновил вопрос, добавив разметку

Comment: А где строчка с `TabControl`? Вот [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3265189/12888024) с примером.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам требуется установить свой стиль для элемента, уже непосредственно в стиле вы можете изменить параметр отвечающий за цвет выбранного элемента.

В качестве примера:

```
        <TabControl Margin="10" BorderThickness="0" Background="LightGray">
        <TabControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                            <Grid Name="Panel">
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                    ContentSource="Header"
                                    Margin="10,2"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="Background" Value="LightSkyBlue" />
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="Background" Value="White" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.Resources>
        <TabItem Header="General">
            <Label Content="Content goes here..." />
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Security" />
        <TabItem Header="Details" />
    </TabControl>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Это работает. А если мне придется делать подобные изменения, но уже в других элементах, мне так же придется создавать для него стиль?

Comment: @Андрей вы можете создать отдельный файл и подключать его как стили и использовать их в других элементах, подробнее вы можете найти по запросу "вешние стили в WPF"

Comment: Это будет работать как css файл в html насколько я понял, спасибо, посмотрю!

Comment: @Андрей да все верно, смысл тот же только на XML пишется

Comment: У меня вот остался еще вопрос, к примеру при нажатии код такой:
<Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="Background" Value="Black" />
Могу ли я так же закрасить границы кнопки используя код ниже, под тем же тригером?
                                    <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Light-Gray"/>

Comment: @Андрей да можете , полькой по-моему вы указали неверное имя цвета , без "-" пишется насколько я помню

Comment: Только что попробовал, но ошибка:
Ошибка XDG0012 Член "BorderBrush" не распознан или недоступен. GreatProgramm MainWindow.xaml 3 
<Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="BorderBrush" Value="White" />
С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: @Андрей вам следует обращаться к элементу рамки и там проводить изменения фона

Comment: @Андрей в качестве примера """ <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="LightSkyBlue" />'''

Comment: а для создания элемента рамки надо использовать код который был выше?
                            <Grid Name="Border">
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                    ContentSource="Header"
                                    Margin="10,2"/>
                            </Grid>

Примерно так?

Comment: @Андрей нет , этот элемент уже внутри TabItem